# Changing Location of user Login Page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I have a login form setup for my WordPress site, but when a user types in the wrong user/pass it directs them to the WP login screen. Is there any way that I can change this without hacking WPMU core?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use below filter to change the login url.

```
add_filter('login_url','wdm_login_url',10,2);
function wdm_login_url($login_url, $redirect)
{
    $login_url = home_url().'/your-page-slug/';
    return $login_url;
}
```

So every time, request goes to wp login screen, it will get redirected to your page

Answer (score 0):

You should use a plugin. A [search for "login"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=login) on WP Plugins can be helpful, maybe check out [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/weasels-login-redirection/).

Answer (score 0):

you can make the login form (wp-login.php), redirect them back by providing a hidden input text name 'redirect_to' in form that you have written. by using 'redirect_to', Wordpress understand that you want after login user will send to the link

forexample :

[pre]http://xxx.xxx/wp-login.php?redirect_to='http://xxx.xxx' [pre]